# An example on "almost a curry" implementation from book "Programming Clojure"

Tags: clojure

In this code,

```
(defn faux-curry [& args] (apply partial partial args))
```

**how should I understand this part**:

```
(apply partial partial args)
```

In my understanding, 'partial' takes a function and some values, then return new a function with some of original function's variables fixed. Does it apply first 'partial' on.. the second 'partial', which do something with the args?? Any better way to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluating by hand with sample arguments may help:

```
(apply partial partial [+ 1 2 3])                     ; 1.
; =>
(partial partial + 1 2 3)                             ; 2.
; =>
(fn [& args] (apply partial + 1 2 (concat [3] args))) ; 3.
```

We're substituting sample arguments in the body of `faux-curry` in 1.; then applying the `apply` by hand in 2.; then applying the first `partial` by hand in 3. (Note that the `[3]` in 3. would actually be a seq of "rest args" to the outer `partial` in compiled code.)

The key thing to note is that `partial` is a function like any other, so in particular it may itself be passed as the first argument to `partial`.

Comment: I'm sure you know that `(apply partial + 1 2 (concat [3] args))` is equivalent to `(apply partial + 1 2 3 args)`, or at least `(apply partial + 1 2 (cons 3 args))`, so I'm curious what made you choose the awkward `concat` construct. Is it instructive in some way that I don't see?

Comment: @amalloy: That's as close as you can get to the actual implementation of `partial` (varargs case: `partial` is `f`; `+`, `1` and `2` are the `argN`; `3` falls into `more`) and I wanted to do "evaluation by rewriting", one function application per step. I suppose it's open to debate whether that makes the answer more instructive.